# LWJGL 3D Rendering not working

Tags: java, 3d, render, lwjgl

I have set up here a main class which renders the blocks from an ArrayList however I only see the last one to be rendered.  Why do I only see the last block in the ArrayList?

This is where I render my blocks in my Main Class:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
Brick.bind();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    Block b;
    for(int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++)
    {
        b = blocks.get(i);
        b.render();
    }
glEnd();
```

glPopMatrix();
   Display.update();

This is where I generate my Blocks:

```
public static void generateMap()
    {
        Block b;
        for(float i = 0; i < 99; i += 3)
        {
            for(float r = 0; r < 99; r += 3)
            {
                b = new Block(i, 0f, r, 3f, 3f, 3f);
                blocks.add(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I have this Block class that I use when making each block:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glTexCoord2f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex3f;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;


public class Block 
{
    protected static float x;
    protected static float y;
    protected static float z;
    protected static float sx;
    protected static float sy;
    protected static float sz;

    public Block(float x, float y, float z, float sx, float sy, float sz)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.sx = sx;
        this.sy = sy;
        this.sz = sz;
    }
    public static void render()
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(x,y,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y,z);
        //Bottom
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y-sy,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(x,y-sx,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(x,y-sx,z);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y-sy,z);
        //Front
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(x,y,z);               
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(x,y-sy,z);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(x-sx,y-sy,z);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y,z);
        //Back
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(x,y,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(x,y-sy,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(x-sx,y-sy,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y,z-sz);
        //Left
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y,z);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(x-sx,y-sy,z);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(x-sx,y-sy,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(x-sx,y,z-sz);
        //Right
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(x,y-sy,z);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(x,y-sy,z-sz);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(x,y,z-sz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you only see the last one, is because all the "Blocks" are on top of each other!

Within the `Block` class you've set the `x`, `y`, `z`, `sx`, `sy`, `sz` variables as static, which they shouldn't be!

Basically the static keyword mean that the value is shared thereby if you change the `x` at one place it will affect everything else also.

**Advice** learn all the Java keywords or atleast all the basic once, because you jump into something as advanced as OpenGL.